# Django: Why does my custom command starts the server?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I am trying to use `Scrapy` with `Django` so I defined the following custom management command:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from scraper.spiders.sparerooms import SpareroomsSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

from scrapy.settings import Settings
import os

class Command(BaseCommand):
  help = "Release the spiders"

  def handle(self, *args, **options):
      os.environ.setdefault('SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'scraper.settings')
      
      process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
      process.crawl(SpareroomsSpider)
      process.start()
```

When I run the command `python3 manager.py crawl` the server is instantiated; I can see libraries and files from another app being loaded before crawling, which is really annoying as I have a large amount of data to load (30min wait).

It wouldn't be such a problem if the server was usable. However, `request.META` is not set (unable to use `request.build_absolute_uri()`) and the endpoints are not reachable `Error 111: Connection Refused.`

All of this works fine if I start the server with `python3 manage.py runserver` and than use the custom command (which loads the server again).

What am I doing wrong? Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server isn't started, it's checked by `django` automatically.

This behavior can be disabled by setting `requires_system_checks` to `False` like so;

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
  help = "Release the spiders"
  requires_system_checks = False

  def handle(self, *args, **options):
      # code goes here
```

Or by using the `skip-checks` argument with the command;

```
python3 manage.py crawl --skip-checks
```